# SQL Server 2008 - On Insert/Update Trigger that copies values to another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have these two tables: Tasks and TasksHistory, from the name you can guess that I want to create a history of everything that's been going on in Tasks. So, every new row inserted or updated needs to go into the history table, just ignoring when it's deleted, keeping the row safe in history. My idea is that history be an **exact replica** of the original table.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You might as well put datetime information into the history table too.   And I'd log deletes too, otherwise you can't determine the state of the table at a particular point in time.

Comment: That is a good idea, pity I have not enough knowledge to put this in practice.

Comment: e.g. just add another column in the history table with a default value of getDate().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simple...

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_Tasks_UI ON Tasks FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON

--Ignore zero row updates, inserts
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) RETURN;

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT TasksHistory
       (col1, col2, ...)
    SELECT
       I.*
    FROM
       INSERTED I
       LEFT JOIN
       DELETED D ON I.key = D.Key
    WHERE
       D.Key IS NULL --insert only
       OR -- need null handling here
       I.col1 <> D.col1 OR I.col2 <> D.col2 OR ...;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    RAISERROR [rethrow caught error using @ErrorNumber, @ErrorMessage, etc]
END CATCH
GO
```

Comment: I think your `I.col1 <> D.col1...` won't deal with changes to/from NULL values correctly?

Comment: Correct, forgot about that sorry

Comment: I couldn't make it work, can you exemplify with the real columns please? The first is auto-increment PK and the columns are: ID, Title, Message, cd_usario, Status, Complete, Priority, DueDate, Owner, Assigned, DateModified, DateCreated

Comment: Says incorrect syntax near 'Key'. And then when I changed it to 'ID' every column I inserted pops a wiggly red line underneath it as if it was all wrong, saying invalid syntax near the column name. Also, since I never used RAISEERROR I googled it up and used as such: RAISEERROR('some error?', 16, 1)