# Insert trigger copy row to another duplicate table SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, insert

**Overview:** Trying to write a trigger for a SQL Server 2008 database. `TableA` and `TableB` have the same schema.

**Aim:** On an insert into `TableA`, copy everything in that row to a new row in `TableB`

**Notes so far:**

Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605362/sql-server-2008-on-insert-update-trigger-that-copies-values-to-another-table) I manage to get most the way, but then stumbled into a problem with

> Cannot use text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and
>   'deleted' tables.

I just have text columns, but I want to copy them too.

I found [this website](http://lazycodeprogrammer.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/how-to-use-inserteddeleted-with.html) which seems to have a workaround but, it is working on update, and I haven't been able to apply it to my insert example...

Any ideas?

**Edit**: purpose is to add functionality to an existing product, I can't change schema of `TableA` unfortunately.

Comment: wouldn't it be time better spent to [replace the `text` columns?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: Sorry? I don't follow...

Comment: I linked to a page of documentation for SQL Server 2008 text, ntext and image data types. At the top, in a large highlight box: "**ntext**, **text**, and **image** data types will be removed in a future version of MicrosoftSQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead."

Comment: Oh right. This was to add functionality to an existing product, so unfortunately I can't change the schema of `TableA`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure why you can't use the example you linked to. It should be as simple as:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_TableA_I
on TableA
after insert
as
    set nocount on

    insert into TableB (ColumnA,ColumnB,/* Columns in table b */)
    select a.ColumnA,a.ColumnB, /* Columns from table a */
    from
        TableA a
            inner join
        inserted i
            on
                a.PKColumn1 = i.PKColumn1 and
                a.PKColumn2 = i.PKColumn2 /* Primary Key columns from table A */
```

Of course, your question doesn't contain any table definitions, so the above will need quite a bit of modification. Hopefully, you can work out what to add/remove from the above, where comments exist.